# Listing tags using pandoc and YAML header

Tags: pandoc

I'm writing in Markdown (with a YAML header) and trying to convert to HTML using pandoc. My YAML header has a "tags" field which is a list, like in the following example:

```
---
title: Title
tags: [one, two]
...

Text.
```

In the final result, I would like to display the tags nicely, in e.g. a comma-delimited list. However, in my pandoc template, the variable `$tags$` only contains the first tag. Doing something like `$for(tags)$$tags$, $endfor$` will generate all the tags, but the trailing comma and space are a problem. How can I display the tags list in the final HTML as `one, two` instead of just `one` or `one, two,`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had missed this in the official documentation under [Templates](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#using-variables-in-templates):

> When variables can have multiple values (for example, author in a
>   multi-author document), you can use the `$for$` keyword:
>
> ```
> $for(author)$
> <meta name="author" content="$author$" />
> $endfor$
> ```
>
> You can optionally specify a separator to be used between consecutive
>   items:
>
> ```
> $for(author)$$author$$sep$, $endfor$
> ```

So in my case I would do `$for(tags)$$tags$$sep$, $endfor$` in the template.